# Remove of switching activity animation on Android

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

There are two activities.

Activity A has a button that can switch to Activity B.

Activity B also has a button that can switch to Activity A.

here is my code,

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.e("current", context.getClass().toString());
    Log.e("changeto", tab.getTag().toString());
    if(context.getClass()==tab.getTag())
        return;

    Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(context,(Class<?>) tab.getTag()));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

I want to remove the animation when i switch the activities, but it doesn't work.

However if I remove

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

it works perfectly. Why?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Activity that you're switching to, try using             `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` either in onResume or in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling startActivity in a tab switch, you're doing it wrong. Tabs are for switching views within the current activity, and switching tabs should never create navigation history. Consider switching a fragment or replacing your view hierarchy with the newly selected tab's content instead.

The more you pursue a path of switching activities for tab selection, the more you will find yourself playing whack-a-mole with subtle user experience bugs that make your app simply feel "wrong."

With your proposed implementation above, the Back button will return to the previously selected tab, breaking the, "never creates navigation history" rule. You may think that finish()ing the current Activity as you start the next can solve this, but you'll still have a host of other issues. Users expect subtle elements of state such as scroll position to persist across tabs. As of Android 4.0 there is an expectation that users should be able to swipe horizontally between tabs (http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html) which you will not be able to accomplish if you are using separate activities for each tab's content.

This is only a small sample, the list just goes on. Tabs should not be used to switch between different Activities.

Comment: i already tried to use viewpager + fragment,
but a Fragment cannot inside another Fragment.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227172/android-inflate-a-layout-contains-fragment

Comment: I am well aware, but you seem to have missed the entire point of my post if you still think your only options are splitting into different activities or nesting fragments. :)