# Android - Error adding fragment to xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I am trying to add a fragment to my xml layout for a dialogfragment but it isnt working, when I try to open the dialogfragment the app crashes because of the fragment being included in the layout

Below is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <fragment
         android:id="@+id/flContent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:padding = "10dp"
         class="com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.AndroidXMLParsingActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my logcat

```
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.BodyDialogue.onCreateView(BodyDialogue.java:64)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1470)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:925)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:299)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.BodyDialogue.onCreateView(BodyDialogue.java:64)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at     android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1470)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:925)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1458)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:438)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is what it is caused by and I dont know how to fix that

```
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0031, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.AndroidXMLParsingActivity
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-17 19:59:02.316: E/AndroidRuntime(5222):     ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

looks there are another id named flContent in your app, try to change the id name.

Comment: I changed the id and it didnt fix it, any other ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227172/android-inflate-a-layout-contains-fragment
take a look this post, looks you made the same mistake.

"You can not have a Fragment inside another Fragment."